# Select all columns, group by one column with other requirements

Tags: sql-server

This is not the original table, I create the similar situation so that I can explain the problem better. 
Let's say I have a table called [student], with 4 columns: [name], [gender], [age], [country].

How to do a 'SELECT *' query that returns the rows that meet this requirements:

1. student must be male
2. only one student from each country
3. if there are more than one students from a country, choose the oldest one

I tried using GROUP BY on [country] but keep getting error "Column '...' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: whatever column not in aggregate, must appear in the GROUP BY clause. Show us your existing code

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Age DESC) RN FROM myTable WHERE gender = 'male') T WHERE RN = 1;` ?

Comment: @ZLK It works! I will mark yours as the answer if you submit as answer. Thanks to you, I just learned about ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Age DESC) RN 
    FROM students 
    WHERE gender = 'male') T 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

The subquery selects only male students, and assigns them a row number based on their age, partitioned by country.